# changing object property values returns null in view

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I'm trying to change some property values of my `account` object. I'm trying to set a value on `domain` and `password`

When I log my object before I send it over to my front end (using vue), the object seems to  be modified to my needs, but when I `console.log()` it in the browser the property values are null.

I'm using Laravel excel to create the accounts. After an account is created I use  events with listeners to send my account objects to my view with pusher.

**How do I do this properly?**

**AccountsImport**

```
class AccountsImport implements ToCollection, withHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        $rows->each(function ($row, $key) {
           $account = Account::create(array_merge([
                'name' => mb_convert_encoding($row['student'], "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($row['student'], "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true)),
                'email' => $row['school_e_mailadres'],
            ], $this->data));
            event(new AccountCreation($account));
        });
    }
}
```

**AccountCreation event gets fired and SetHostingAccount listener will run**

```
public function handle(AccountCreation $event) 
{
    $generator = new ComputerPasswordGenerator();
    $generator->setUppercase()->setLowercase()->setNumbers()->setSymbols(false)->setLength(20);
    $password = $generator->generatePassword();

    $domain = preg_replace('/\s+/', '.', mb_strtolower($event->account->name . ' mtantwerp.eu'));
    $event->account->{"domain"} = $domain;
    $event->account->{"password"} = $password;

    \Log::debug($event->account);

    return $event->account; 
}
```

**Vue**

```
 created() {
    Echo.channel("account-channel").listen("AccountCreation", e => {
      console.log(e.account);
      this.accounts.unshift(e.account);
    });      
  }
```

**Log results**

Example result of `\Log::debug($event->account)`

```
{"name":"John Doe","email":"john.doe@student.kdg.be","package":"KDG student","id":577,"domain":"john.doe.mtantwerp.eu","password":"r5RSEvQBYnTF7RkPtL8Y"}
```

`Console.log(e.account)` in view

```
Object
domain: null
email: "john.doe@student.kdg.be"
id: 703
name: "Doe John"
package: "KDG student"
password: null
status: "created"
```

Comment: What if you save the model in the Event class, and refresh the model in the `each` method. 

Another tip: Create static methods to generate the password and domain. And when creating use the `Account::insert();` method to minimalize the amount of insert queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not persisting your data to the model.

```
public function handle(AccountCreation $event) 
{
    $generator = new ComputerPasswordGenerator();
    $generator->setUppercase()->setLowercase()->setNumbers()->setSymbols(false)->setLength(20);
    $password = $generator->generatePassword();

    $domain = preg_replace('/\s+/', '.', mb_strtolower($event->account->name . ' mtantwerp.eu'));
    $event->account->{"domain"} = $domain;
    $event->account->{"password"} = $password;

    // persist 
    $event->account->save();

    return $event->account; 
}
```

Edit: I think there are two ways you can handle this.

Either you re-broadcast the event after updating your account details:

```
public function handle(AccountCreation $event) 
{
    $generator = new ComputerPasswordGenerator();
    $generator->setUppercase()->setLowercase()->setNumbers()->setSymbols(false)->setLength(20);
    $password = $generator->generatePassword();

    $domain = preg_replace('/\s+/', '.', mb_strtolower($event->account->name . ' mtantwerp.eu'));
    $event->account->{"domain"} = $domain;
    $event->account->{"password"} = $password;

    // persist 
    $event->account->save();

    // broadcast will have updated account details 
    // after it was persisted
    broadcast($event);

    return $event->account; 
}
```

In this case, you would also need to check for whether the account has a domain on the `Vue` component.

```
if(e.account.domain) {
    this.accounts.unshift(e.account);
}
```

This should work. However, I'd rather you consider creating a new event which will better describe what you are tring to do.
In this case, the account is being updated. So you would create a new `AccountWasUpdated` event and you will have `Echo` listen to it instead.

```
public function handle(AccountCreation $event) 
{
    $generator = new ComputerPasswordGenerator();
    $generator->setUppercase()->setLowercase()->setNumbers()->setSymbols(false)->setLength(20);
    $password = $generator->generatePassword();

    $domain = preg_replace('/\s+/', '.', mb_strtolower($event->account->name . ' mtantwerp.eu'));
    $event->account->{"domain"} = $domain;
    $event->account->{"password"} = $password;

    // persist 
    $event->account->save();

    event(new AccountWasUpdated($event->account)); 

    return $event->account; 
}
```

Instead of having Echo listen to the `AccountCreation` event, it would listen to the `AccountWasUpdated` event and it will contain the new Account Object.

Comment: I tried this. The model gets updated but when I send the `account` object `domain` and `password` are still null.

Comment: Can we see that code? Where you are sending it to pusher?

Comment: Edited with a possible implementation.